# WPF writing html to a rich text box

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, windows

I am working on a WPF Windows application using C# code. This is an application I inherited. I only have limited experience using WPF. 
I have a Rich Text Box control which is used to build an Email using html. There is code to read the Rich Text Box contents and store the results as html in a database. This code is working. I need to write the reverse that is writing the html to the rich text box so it appears as text.

Below is the code I have to read the rich text box.

```
 TextRange xaml = new TextRange(EmailBodyRichTextBox.Document.ContentStart, EmailBodyRichTextBox.Document.ContentEnd);
            MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
            xaml.Save(ms, DataFormats.Xaml);
            string xamlString = ASCIIEncoding.Default.GetString(ms.ToArray());

            string html = HTMLConverter.HtmlFromXamlConverter.ConvertXamlToHtml("<FlowDocument>" + xamlString + "</FlowDocument>");

            html = HttpUtility.HtmlEncode(html);
```

Comment: One question to help you get better answers - Are you trying to get the source code of the HTML, are you trying to remove all the markup and just get the plaintext from the HTML document, or are you trying to convert HTML to rich text?

Comment: It's the later. For example, if the text was bold and then saved as html, it should show up as bold in the RT box.

Answer (score 0):

From the code you post above , it seems , you are saving the text in the rich text box to xaml, and then translate the xaml to HTML.

if you want to reverse, then translate your HTML to xaml and then load it to the rich text box.

Comment: The part I'm having a problem with is getting the exact syntax. If someone could post a sample or point me to one, that would be great.

Answer (score 0):

To save the RichTextBox's content to a regular string that you can save in a database:

```
string formattedEmail = XamlWriter.Save(EmailBodyRichTextBox.Document);
```

To reload the RichTextBox from the string:

```
EmailBodyRichTextBox.Document = XamlReader.Parse(formattedEmail);
```

If you only want to store the emails in the database and then reload them to RichTextBoxes, there is no point in converting to HTML, it can only introduce conversion format mismatches.

Comment: Cannot implicitly convert type 'object' to 'System.Windows.Documents.FlowDocument'